# type of method in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I need to send method as parameter (MS Visual Studio 2008):

```
void Apply(Node<string>* node, void (visit(TreeEditor* self, Node<string> *)))
```

but this error occurs:

error C2664: 'TreeEditor::Apply' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'void (__thiscall TreeEditor::* )(TreeEditor *,Node *)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(TreeEditor *,Node *)' d:\ed7\saod\labs\oopkkrtree\treeeditor\treeeditor.h 74

I tried to use this type:

```
void Apply(Node<string>* node, void(__thiscall TreeEditor::*)(TreeEditor *,Node<string> *))
```

and now it works, but I don't know how to specify the name of the parameter (for ex: void(func(int)))

I can't send static method.

I tried to do this:

```
void Apply(Node<string>* node, void(visit)(__thiscall TreeEditor::*)(TreeEditor *,Node<string> *))
void Apply(Node<string>* node, void(visit(__thiscall TreeEditor::*)(TreeEditor *,Node<string> *)))
void Apply(Node<string>* node, void(__thiscall TreeEditor::*)(visit(TreeEditor *,Node<string> *)))
```

but it didn't work.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name goes after the `*`:

```
void Apply(Node<string>* node, void(TreeEditor::*visit)(TreeEditor *,Node<string> *))
```

The `__thiscall` is unnecessary and will only work on Visual C++ (IIRC). Also you'll need to pass or otherwise appropriate a `TreeEditor` to call the method on.

I would also recommend providing a `typedef` for that callback type:

```
typedef void(TreeEditor::*TreeEditorVisitor)(TreeEditor*, Node<string>*);
```

Then you can write `Apply` like this:

```
void Apply(Node<string>* node, TreeEditorVisitor visit)
```

Comment: Thank you. But when I try to call this method like: visit(this, node) or visit(node), I get this error: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2(1) arguments

Comment: @Str you have to call method pointers in a special way: `(this->*visit)(node)` (if `this` is a pointer to the `TreeEditor` you want to call `visit` on). Also if this answer answered your question, please accept it by clicking the check mark beside it.

Answer (score 1):

By default, __thiscall means the function is a class member function, and __cdecl is non-member function.  So your error message is complaining that your function declaration requested a non-member function pointer, but you are passing a member function pointer in.

So you can either change the declaration of Apply

```
void Apply(Node<string>* node, void (TreeEditor::*visit)(TreeEditor* self, Node<string> *))
```

or have a wrapper function that calls your object's method, and pass that function in.